# kafka-avro-console-consumer is command is not available in `confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka`

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform

I've below docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.0.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
    - "2181:2181"
    environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
    ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:6.0.0
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper
    ports:
    - "29092:29092"
    environment:
    KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
    KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
    KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

When I run `docker-compose exec kafka bash` I get the bash prompt.

In the bash prompt I've `kafka-console-consumer` but I don't have access to `kafka-avro-console-consumer`?

How can I get access to `kafka-avro-console-consumer`? Is it not in $PATH but in some other directory?

I tried to use `find` and `which` commands but those are not present in docker running container

Answer (score 5):

use confluentinc/cp-schema-registry

```
docker run confluentinc/cp-schema-registry \
 kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 --topic quickstart-jdbc-test --from-beginning --max-messages 10
```